# Javascript: change CSS element if jquery GET failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a Javascript in my header that calls an external server to retrieve some information, like this:

```
$.getJSON("https://domain.tld/json/", function (something) {
            var results = //stuff that formats the result, not relevant here;
            window.$info = results;
    }).fail(function(){
        // here's where I need the code to make the warning appear 
        });
```

Then in the body I have a warning that should pop up in case the GET request failed:

`<div id="warning">Warning text</div>`

Problem: the javascript is in the header and I can't change the "warning" div because it has not been created yet.
If I use `document.getElementById("warning").style.display='block';` I get an error message saying it is null.

So how do I use the .fail() part of the jquery GET function to make the warning div appear (that is created later) in case the GET function has failed? Or is that not possible? And some 'solution' I tried (don't remember what exactly) even delayed the loading of the whole page. I'd like to avoid that as well.

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your jQuery in a document ready function? That will wait for the DOM to load before executing the jQuery.

Comment: That did it. I didn't even have to wrap the whole jquery function in it, just the part that toggles the visibility, like:
    }).fail(function(){
              $(document).ready(function()
                $("#warning").show();
                  });
               });

Comment: P.S. Ok, so comments can only be edited for 5 minutes. :) Coop, I don't know how to mark your comment as the 'correct' answer. Not possible for comments it seems. Sorry about that. And thank you all.

Comment: Jolly good. I've added my comment as an answer now for the befit of others. Feel free to mark it as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is trying to execute and look for things before the DOM has loaded. You can solve this problem by making sure your javascript only fires when the DOM is ready. In jQuery you do that like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //your code here
});
```

The native javascript version of this is much more complicated so I won't post that here. However you could also wait for the entire page to load before executing the code like so:

```
window.onload = function(){
  //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should hide your html element initialy

```
<div id="warning" style="display:none;">Warning text</div>
```

And you can call show() method to display hidden element when get request failed

```
$("#warning").show();
```